# How to clear an Input after form submission in Aurelia

Tags: javascript, aurelia

Is there an Aurelia way to accomplish what I am trying to do? After I click add, I want the input to be set back to zero. Here is the app.js file

```
export class App {
  constructor() {
    this.message = 'Hello World!';
    this.array = [];
    this.array.push("Hello");
  }
  addToArray()
  {
    this.array.push(this.hello);
    hello = "";
  }
}
```

I tried setting the `var hello` back to an empty string, thinking Aurelia had them two way bounded. But then I thought that was silly, because you might want to mutate/manipulate the variable while in the function, and you wouldn't want the user to see it, so I guess setting hello back to an empty string wouldn't work. Here is the html.

```
  <form submit.trigger="addToArray()">
    <input type='text' value.bind="hello">
    <input type='submit' value="add">
    </form>

    <ul>
      <li repeat.for="a of array">${a}</li> 
      </ul>
```

Comment: it turns out they are bounded. Simple answer here, i needed to use `this.hello = ""`. I guess if I wanted to manipulate any variable, I would have to set it equal to another variable within the function.

Comment: Would you mind posting that you forgot to use `this.` in front of `hello` as an answer to your own question? I'll give it an upvote since it is such a common issue.

Answer (score 1):

It turns out they are bounded! Simple answer here, i needed to use `this.hello = ""`

Potentially, the model wouldn't update until the function has finished running, my guess is this is how it works. So as long as the bounded variable is set to something user friendly at the end of the function you should be fine making any changes to the value during execution

Comment: Yes, when you bind a variable to a native DOM input control in Aurelia the variable is two way bound by convention (you can change this by using value.one-way="hello" if you want). However, when you bind a variable to something that is a native DOM control, the variable is one-way bound by convention (use value.two-way to make it two way bound, or specify the default two way binding inside the component that you are binding to).